# how to print special characters which are a string in variable with php?

Tags: php, string, variables, special-characters

I'm making this chat server, but it doesn't work quite well. When you send a piece of text, it first gets encoded by the function `base64_encode()` and then gets sent to a MySQL database.
Then the receiver gets the text from that same MySQL database, which is of course first decoded by the function `base64_decode()`.

The only problem is with the special characters like `\n` `\'` and `\t`: when I get the data from the database and print it between two textarea tags, I see `\n` as a string, and not as actual line breaks.

In short, I need to fix this problem:

```
$String = 'Line 1 \n Line 2';
print '<textarea>' . $String . '</textarea>';

//The result I want
//<textarea> Line 1
//Line 2 </textarea>
```

The function `nl2br` doesn't work, because tags inside a textarea tag won't work, and also because there other characters like apostrophes.

Could anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your string into double quotes, for special characters to be evaluated.

```
$String = "Line 1 \n Line 2";
print '<textarea>' . $String . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: That's true, but the variable comes actually out of a query. So first the string is send to my database (because it's a chat server), and then take it out of my database with a select query, so the variable is already defined by another user.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have to escape '\n' before you write it into the database. Put another slash in front of '\n', before you write your string to the database, like this '\\n'. So it would look something like this. `Line1 \\n Line2`

Answer (score 0):

If you change this:

```
$String = 'Line 1 \n Line 2';
print '<textarea>' . $String . '</textarea>';
```

to this:

```
$String = "Line 1 \n Line 2"; // double quote
print '<textarea>' . $String . '</textarea>';
```

... you will get the output you want.

Comment: That's true, but the variable comes actually out of a query. So first the string is send to my database (because it's a chat server), and then take it out of my database with a select query, so the variable is already defined by another user.

Answer (score 0):

This one is also works same as using `" ... "`, however maybe helps in your case:

```
$string = <<<EOT
Line 1 \n Line 2
EOT;

echo '<textarea>' . $string . '</textarea>';
```

As the others said, your problem is `Single-Quotes`.